# Почему не работает флаг?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public float seeDistance = 10f;
//дистанция от которой он начинает видеть игрока
//дистанция до атаки
public float attackDistance = 400f;
//скорость енеми
public float PingPongspeed;
public float speedMove;
//игрок
public Transform target;
public Vector3 start; // начало
public Vector3 end; // конец
public float time; // время перемещения
private float timer;

public GameObject prefabEffect;
public Transform point;
public bool flag;

private void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    start = new Vector3(100,-4,394);
    end = new Vector3(-100, -4, 394);
    if(flag)
    {
        InvokeRepeating("createLaser", 5, 1);
    }


}

private void Update()
{


    if (target != null && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > attackDistance)
    {
        flag = false;
        // transform.forward = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speedMove);


    }
    else
    {
        flag = true;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(-125, -4, transform.position.z), new Vector3(125, 20, transform.position.z), Mathf.PingPong(timer, time));
        timer += Time.deltaTime * PingPongspeed;
        LootAtPlayer();





     }
```

Comment: Не запускается метод InvokeRepeating при выполнении условия

Answer (score 2):

Не особо понятна логика вашей программы. Вы бы хотя бы описали, что должно быть. Но InvokeRepeating не выполняется, потому что вы вызваете эту функцию в методе start. Этот метод срабатывает только один раз при старте этого кода, и всё.А булевую переменную flag вы меняете уже в методе Update. И flag действительно становится true, но метод InvokeRepeating вызвался только один раз в начале программы, и больше он не срабатывает. Как вариант перенести код

```
 if(flag)
    {
        InvokeRepeating("createLaser", 5, 1);
    }
```

В начало метода Update. Тогда он будет вызываться каждый раз, когда flag == true, если это то, чего вы хотите...